# How to extract certain files from a directory in shell?

Tags: linux, files, cp

I made a simple shell script that takes a command line directory and extracts all of its contents to the current directory the script is running in.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -v -R $1/* .
```

I want to extend on this, let's say I want to pull out all of the PNG files in directory A and **ONLY** the PNG files.

My first thought is to search for all files in the directory that end with a .png and cat it, but I have no idea how to then copy ONLY those files into the directory.

Comment: Wildcard all files containing png extension within the directory. **/*.png**

Answer (score 1):

When copying gets complicated, `rsync` is often useful:

```
rsync -mva --include '*/' --include '*.png' --exclude '*' "$1/" .
```

Before you run that for real, though, do a dry-run (option: `-n`) so you can verify it does what you want:

```
rsync -nmva --include '*/' --include '*.png' --exclude '*' "$1/" .
```

#### How it works

- `-v` (optional) tells rsync to be verbose, so you can see what's going on.
- `-a` (optional) tells rsync to preserve attributes.
- `--include '*/'` tells rsync to include all directories
- `--include '*.png'` tells rsync to include all files with `.png` suffix.
- `--exclude '*'` tells rsync to exclude all files not matched above.
- `-m` tells rsync not to copy directories that would be empty on the receiving side.

Note that the include/exclude options have to be specified in order.

Comment: This seems to find all of the c files correctly, but how do I then copy them? Do I just use -cp after rsync?

Comment: @Orcka `rsync` copies files.  It can be used instead of `cp`.  Just use it without `-n` and it will recursively copy whole directory structures.

Comment: All that it is doing is extracting the sub-directories with the c files, but doesn't take out the files themselves. So I basically have a bunch of empty directories that have a couple of .c files hiding somewhere.

Comment: @Orcka If you don't want the empty directories, add the `-m` option (answer updated with `-m`),   With `-m`, only directories that are needed to hold `.png` files will be copied.    Also, the command should skip over the `.c` files, keeping only `.png` files.

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
find "$1" -name '*.png' -exec cp -v -- {} ./ \;
```

or (with GNU `cp`) more efficiently

```
find "$1" -name '*.png' -exec cp -vt ./ -- {} +
```

or if your shell supports it, you can use globbing - for example in `bash`

```
shopt -s globstar

cp -v -- "$1"/**/*.png ./
```

Comment: Hmm.  This copies all files to the current directory, removing the directory structure.  This might just be what the OP wanted:  +1.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. when I ~ls, the directory hasn't changed, there should be some png files floating around. Bear in mind that there are sub-directories in this directory.

Comment: If you replace the command by `find "$1" -name '*.png'` does it return anything? do the files actually have the `.png` extension, or are they in just in PNG format (with arbitrary - or no - extension)? if the latter, some additional processing (e.g. the `file` or `mimetype` commands) will be necessary in order to to identify them.

Comment: Replace it with what, my original code? 

Also the files have the extension .png, no need to identify the files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're apparently using bash, you can use the `globstar` filename expansion feature:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp **/*.png /some/destination
```

Beware of colliding filenames -- only one will survive the copy!